# From Windows to Ubuntu.. Questions

Tags: security

It's my first time on this forum as well as becoming a user of any Linux distribution. I've been getting in to Linux primarily because I've been taking some courses at my university as well as achieving my goals to become a Network Administrator.

I have some question's about Ubuntu (which I downloaded and install over my W10 on my new Lenovo 710).

- How can I maximize my security overall on the distribution? I've enabled ip-tables and closed ports that I know I won't be using. *I don't believe in GUI Anti-viruses as Linux isn't really targeted by viruses unlike Windows Etc.
- What would someone recommend I start doing to learn more about the in's and out's of the operating system with the goal in mind to becoming a very knowledgeable Admin?
- There are numerous YouTube videos as well as Guides/Tutorials on how to use Ubuntu, but me being me I enjoy terminal based commands as GUI is just EH! Where are some good places to visit? I've heard numerous sites and videos but never one structured place to go.

I'd appreciate any sort of feedback. I'm here to learn and open to sharing my experiences as well as joining the wonderful community of open-source.

--Eurx

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is not a forum. This is a question answer site. Please read the [Help pages](https://askubuntu.com/help) to understand the right format to ask questions here.  The questions you are asking are too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user68186 said, this is not a forum. However, I guess I can help you out.

If you search for "**Ubuntu basic terminal commands**" or "**Ubuntu terminal for beginners**", you'll find a huge list of sites with tutorials and information.

I can suggest some of them:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal
2. https://techlog360.com/basic-ubuntu-commands-terminal-shortcuts-linux-beginner/
3. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/10-basic-linux-commands-that-every-linux-newbies-should-remember
4. http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/07/20/top-17-terminal-commands-every-ubuntu-user-should-know-about/

In order to learn how to use the terminal, you should spend some time searching on Google. You can do things quicker and easier with a few keystrokes.